# Http get request in Android

Tags: android, http, request

I need help with sending http get request. Like this:

```
URL connectURL;
connectURL = new URL(address);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)connectURL.openConnection(); 
// do some setup
conn.setDoInput(true); 
conn.setDoOutput(true); 
conn.setUseCaches(false); 
conn.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
// connect and flush the request out
conn.connect();
conn.getOutputStream().flush();
// now fetch the results
String response = getResponse(conn);
et.setText(response);
```

I searched the web but any method I try, the code fails at `'conn.connect();'`. Any clues?

Comment: How does it "fail"?  What is the error in the log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want some [demo code](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) then try following:

```
 URL url = new URL("url.com");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
   } finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
```

and this:

```
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
     urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

     OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
     writeStream(out);

     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
   } finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `readStream` and `writeStream` are just placeholder, which tells you need to read the stream at here and process further.

Answer (score 4):

Very hard to tell without the actual error message. Random thought: did you add the internet permission to you manifest?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```