# How we send registration data along with WebServices in Android

Tags: android, web-services

I have one android application to be made.
In the Registration process i have to fill in two fields

- Phone number
- Name

Along with these two fields i have to also send my deviceid, current time and OS version dynamically.

How can i do so?

My Web Service is 
http://frapp.badoniya.com/webservices/register.php?username=Vijay%20&deviceid=12345&mobile=98XXXXXXXX&platform=Android&os_version=4.0

Please give me a step wise solution.
Because i am very new in programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an AsyncTask to achieve what you are looking for. Here are few examples on how to use an AsyncTask, Send a GET request and Sending a POST request. For this scenario you must send a GET request.

**GET Request**
[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634052/http-get-request-in-android)
[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959316/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-http-get-request-in-android)

**POST Request**
[Example 1](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)

**AsyncTask**
[Example 1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use an AsyncTask and inside the async task you can use HTTPPost or HTTPGet requests to call a webservice using parameters